# PHP: Certain elements missing from array

Tags: php, arrays, ubuntu, nginx, missing-data

So I've got a bug somewhere in my code that stops certain elements from being included in an array, this is the best way that I can explain it.

I've got a static file (Config.php) that contains a large array full of data, within this array there is another array with a key of "PredefinedValues", this contains values that need to be referenced by other parts of the script.

The issue: I can reference everything in the array except for 5 values that I recently added, I var_dump the array and they're not there when they're clearly in the file. I've reuploaded the files to my web server around 5/6 times, restarted php, restarted the server and it's not fixed. The issue does not occur on my local machine (Windows) but it does occur on my Linux server (Ubuntu).

The array is structured like this:

```
<?php

global $Configuration;

$Configuration = array(

    "PredefinedValues" => array(

        "Example" => "example",
        "123" => "test",
        "abc" => "test2",
        "asdf" => "value2",
        "val2" => "value3",

    ),
```

And the values I wouldn't be able to access are abc/asdf - but all of the values above/below it are fine.

Init file:

```
require_once("config/Config.php");

Class Lib
{

    Public $Root            =   __DIR__;
    Public $DependencyRoot;


    Public function __construct()
    {

        //error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

        error_reporting(E_ALL);


        Global $Configuration;

        var_dump($Configuration["PredefinedValues"]);

        $this->DependencyRoot = __DIR__ . "/libs/Dependencies/";

    }

}

?>
```

Var_dumping the array within the __construct doesn't work, but when I var_dump it straight after the require, it works fine.

Any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `var_dump` inside `__construct` will only be executed when a new object is created. Try to create a `new Lib()` and look the result.

Comment: Tried that, still no luck. I've narrowed the issue down a bit though, it only seems to happen on 1 machine, I tried it on a newly deployed server and the code worked fine. Not too sure why it isn't working on this machine in paticular though.

Comment: It's really odd. It could be a cache problem. Have you tried to delete all files in the server and upload again (and not just overwrite)? You can try using `touch` in all files to update the modified time.